# Thymeleaf static imports java package

Tags: thymeleaf

In my thymeleaf template I sometimes refer to Java enum classes (and static methods). For example:

[[${T(amc.mb.catmaker.enums.SortParameter).DEPARTMENT.datatablesColumnName}]] is used to invoke the getter for the datatablesColumnName of the DEPARTMENT object.
Since this is very verbose (especially if multiple enums are being used) I wonder if the enum class can somehow be imported as static.